# Need to get all combinations of several lists, taking sets amounts from each list

Tags: c#, algorithm, list

```
class Employee
{
    int id;
    Position position;
}

class Position
{
    string name;
}

public List<List<Tuple<Position, Employee>>> getAllCombinations(Dictionary<Position, int> positionToCountMap, List<Employee> allEmployees)
{
}
```

positionToCountMap to would be something like this: {"Manager", 1}, {"Developer", "3"}, {"PM", "1"}   (it's unknown how many keys there are)

I need to return a list of all possible combinations of allEmployees such that it satisfies the count requirements in the positionToCountMap. I need al combinations of 1 manager, 3 developers and 1 PM. My first step was to create a new dictionary of position to a list of employees with that position.

```
var positionToEmployeeMap = new Dictionary<Position, List<Employee>>()
//Loop through allEmployees adding each to this dictionary
```

Now the problem becomes that I have several lists, and I need to find all possible combinations taking the amount specified in positionToCountMap from each list.

Is this a good way to approach the problem? Even if it is, I can't wrap my head around how I would actually brute force this. I was originally trying to think of some recursive solution, but the size of the list may be large enough that recursion might not be a great choice. I'm stuck and could use some advice.

**EDIT**
I *think* I have a solution, though it's not great and i'd still love to get some advice.

```
var positionToEmployeeMap = new Dictionary<Position, List<Employee>>()
//Loop through allEmployees adding each to this dictionary

var relevantLists = new List<Employee>();
//for each key in positionToCountMap, find the list in positionToEmployeeMap and add it to relevantLists

var allCombos = new List<List<Employee>>();
//Loop through relevantLists. For each list, recursively generate all possible combinations of sublists of size N, where N is the number in positionToCountMap. Add a list of all the combinations to allCombos

//recursively loop through allCombos finding all possible combinations taking 1 element from each list
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd use LINQ.  You can do something similar to a SQL `CROSS JOIN` operation with the following:

```
var ListA = new List<object>();
var ListB = new List<object>();
var ListC = new List<object>();

var result = (from a in listA
  from b in listB
  from c in listC
  select new { a, b, c }).ToList();
```

This will result in a list including all combinations of the values in ListA, ListB, and ListC.

Comment: The problem is that it needs to be more than just one from each list. Like in the above example in the OP, I would need one item from list A, three from list B and one from list C.

Comment: Also, it's unknown how many keys are in the dictionary, so I can't just assume it will only be 3 lists.